# I am getting undefined reference to functions in DHT22 library on VS Code. How do I fix it?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, undefined-reference, esp-idf

I have a project that involves a ESP32 collecting temperature and humidity data from a DHT22. I am trying to use the functions of an external DHT22 library that I downloaded from github.
When I tried building my code to test it on ESP32, I got undefined reference to functions as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL4fa.png). How do I fix this problem?

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "rom/ets_sys.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "DHT22.h"

void DHT_task(void *pvParameter)
{
    setDHTgpio( 4 );
    printf( "Starting DHT Task\n\n");

    while(1) {
    
        printf("=== Reading DHT ===\n" );
        int ret = readDHT();
        
        errorHandler(ret);

        printf( "Hum %.1f\n", getHumidity() );
        printf( "Tmp %.1f\n", getTemperature() );
        
        vTaskDelay( 3000 / portTICK_RATE_MS );
    }
}

void app_main()
{
    nvs_flash_init();
    vTaskDelay( 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS );
    xTaskCreate( &DHT_task, "DHT_task", 2048, NULL, 5, NULL );
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build - Build project",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPath} ${config:idf.espIdfPath}/tools/idf.py build",
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPathWin} ${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}\\tools\\idf.py build",
                "options": {
                    "env": {
                        "PATH": "${env:PATH};${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "PATH": "${env:PATH}:${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                }
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "owner": "cpp",
                    "fileLocation": [
                        "relative",
                        "${workspaceFolder}"
                    ],
                    "pattern": {
                        "regexp": "^\\.\\.(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3,
                        "severity": 4,
                        "message": 5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "owner": "cpp",
                    "fileLocation": "absolute",
                    "pattern": {
                        "regexp": "^[^\\.](.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3,
                        "severity": 4,
                        "message": 5
                    }
                }
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Set ESP-IDF Target",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${command:espIdf.setTarget}",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": "absolute",
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(//d+):(//d+)://s+(warning|error)://s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Clean - Clean the project",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPath} ${config:idf.espIdfPath}/tools/idf.py fullclean",
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPathWin} ${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}\\tools\\idf.py fullclean",
                "options": {
                    "env": {
                        "PATH": "${env:PATH};${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "PATH": "${env:PATH}:${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                }
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "owner": "cpp",
                    "fileLocation": [
                        "relative",
                        "${workspaceFolder}"
                    ],
                    "pattern": {
                        "regexp": "^\\.\\.(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3,
                        "severity": 4,
                        "message": 5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "owner": "cpp",
                    "fileLocation": "absolute",
                    "pattern": {
                        "regexp": "^[^\\.](.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3,
                        "severity": 4,
                        "message": 5
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Flash - Flash the device",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPath} ${config:idf.espIdfPath}/tools/idf.py -p ${config:idf.port} -b ${config:idf.flashBaudRate} flash",
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPathWin} ${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}\\tools\\idf.py flash -p ${config:idf.portWin} -b ${config:idf.flashBaudRate}",
                "options": {
                    "env": {
                        "PATH": "${env:PATH};${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "PATH": "${env:PATH}:${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                }
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "owner": "cpp",
                    "fileLocation": [
                        "relative",
                        "${workspaceFolder}"
                    ],
                    "pattern": {
                        "regexp": "^\\.\\.(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3,
                        "severity": 4,
                        "message": 5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "owner": "cpp",
                    "fileLocation": "absolute",
                    "pattern": {
                        "regexp": "^[^\\.](.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3,
                        "severity": 4,
                        "message": 5
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Monitor: Start the monitor",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPath} ${config:idf.espIdfPath}/tools/idf.py -p ${config:idf.port} monitor",
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPathWin} ${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}\\tools\\idf.py -p ${config:idf.portWin} monitor",
                "options": {
                    "env": {
                        "PATH": "${env:PATH};${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "PATH": "${env:PATH}:${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                }
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "owner": "cpp",
                    "fileLocation": [
                        "relative",
                        "${workspaceFolder}"
                    ],
                    "pattern": {
                        "regexp": "^\\.\\.(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3,
                        "severity": 4,
                        "message": 5
                    }
                },
                {
                    "owner": "cpp",
                    "fileLocation": "absolute",
                    "pattern": {
                        "regexp": "^[^\\.](.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 2,
                        "column": 3,
                        "severity": 4,
                        "message": 5
                    }
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": "Flash - Flash the device"
        },
        {
            "label": "OpenOCD: Start openOCD",
            "type": "shell",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "never",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "new"
            },
            "command": "openocd -s ${command:espIdf.getOpenOcdScriptValue} ${command:espIdf.getOpenOcdConfigs}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "openocd.exe -s ${command:espIdf.getOpenOcdScriptValue} ${command:espIdf.getOpenOcdConfigs}",
                "options": {
                    "env": {
                        "PATH": "${env:PATH};${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "PATH": "${env:PATH}:${config:idf.customExtraPaths}"
                }
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": "absolute",
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "adapter",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPath}",
            "isBackground": true,
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "PATH": "${env:PATH}:${config:idf.customExtraPaths}",
                    "PYTHONPATH": "${command:espIdf.getExtensionPath}/esp_debug_adapter/debug_adapter"
                }
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "background": {
                    "beginsPattern": "\bDEBUG_ADAPTER_STARTED\b",
                    "endsPattern": "DEBUG_ADAPTER_READY2CONNECT",
                    "activeOnStart": true
                },
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\s(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+),(\\d+)\\s-(.+)\\s(ERROR)",
                    "file": 8,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 9
                }
            },
            "args": [
                "${command:espIdf.getExtensionPath}/esp_debug_adapter/debug_adapter_main.py",
                "-e",
                "${workspaceFolder}/build/${command:espIdf.getProjectName}.elf",
                "-s",
                "${command:espIdf.getOpenOcdScriptValue}",
                "-ip",
                "localhost",
                "-dn",
                "${config:idf.adapterTargetName}",
                "-om",
                "connect_to_instance",
                "-I", "C:\\Users\\vorte\\ESP-IDF\\Projects\\hello_world\\main",
            ],
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:idf.pythonBinPathWin}",
                "options": {
                    "env": {
                        "PATH": "${env:PATH};${config:idf.customExtraPaths}",
                        "PYTHONPATH": "${command:espIdf.getExtensionPath}/esp_debug_adapter/debug_adapter"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ESP-IDF",
            "compilerPath": "${default}",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "includePath": [
                "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Users\\vorte\\ESP-IDF\\Projects\\hello_world\\main"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components",
                    "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components",
                    "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "C:\\Users\\vorte\\ESP-IDF\\Projects\\hello_world\\main"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: You have issue with the linker. If you are using static library, include the library in the library path. If not, you might be required to add the sources to the build, not only the headers. If both are not the case, provide more details of which library you are using.

Comment: I believe the DHT22.h is a static library. What do you mean by library path?

Comment: You need to tell the linker where to find the library. The `.h` is not the library, it's the header file containing the declarations.

Comment: I'm confused with what a library looks like. How do I tell the linker to find the library? I've never done this before.

Comment: @JordanKwatt Could you post a link to the DHT11 library which you are using? We need more information to make suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Add DHT22 c file to CMAKElist File inside the main folder